# How to do a background task before a fragment gets attached to an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to do a background task in a fragment of which when it is completed it can then attach the fragment to the activity.

I tried doing the background task in the onAttach() method using doAsyn{} but the fragment still get attached before the task gets completed.

The question is how do i make sure that a task get completed before a fragment is attached to an activity or better still which method is best used to carry out background task before a fragment is attached to an activity?

Comment: Do the task before the `FragmentTransaction::commit` is called, also if it is a true background task then use a `Service`

Comment: Mark Keen, perfect it solved my problem... thanks

Comment: please how do I mark this as solved/right answer?